# I want to store 1 month order data in one the problem is try to change date in day after day but it is storing 1970 date

Tags: laravel

This is my controller.  I want to store 1 month order data in one.  The problem is try to change date in day after day but it is storing 1970 date.

```
public function orderdatastore(Request $request){
    $userid = 'GWU458910';
    $orderid = "ORD".rand(10,99).rand(25,35).rand(155,255);
    $pid = $request->product_id;
    // Fetch Product name ny Product id 
    $product_data = DB::table('products')->where('product_id',$pid)->first();
    $product_name = $product_data->product_name;
    $selling_price = $product_data->selling_price;
    // Fetch user name by user id 
    $customer_data = DB::table('customer_registrations')->where('customer_id',$userid)->first();
    $customer = $product_data->product_name;

    $fdate=$request->start_date;
    $tdate=$request->end_date;
    $datetime1 = strtotime($fdate); // convert to timestamps
    $datetime2 = strtotime($tdate); // convert to timestamps
    $days = (int)(($datetime2 - $datetime1)/86400);
    
    for ($i=0; $i <= $days ; $i++) { 
        $order = new Orders;
        $order->order_id = $orderid;
        $order->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $order->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $order->user_id = $request->userid;
        $order->user_name = $customer;
        $order->product_name = $product_name;
        $order->product_quantity = $request->quantity;

        if($i==0) {
            $order->order_date = $fdate;
        }else{
            $mydate = $fdate;
            $daystosum = '1';
            $dd = (int)(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($mydate.' + '.$daystosum.' days')));
            $d2 = date('Y-m-d', $dd);
            $d3 = $d2;
            $order->order_date = $d3;
        }

        $order->product_selling_price = $selling_price;
        // $order->volume = $request->volume;
        $order->order_start_date = $fdate;
        $order->order_end_date = $tdate;
        $order->payment_mode = $request->payment_mode;
        $order->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $order->save();
        echo "All data Saved";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your existing code is this line:

```
$dd = (int)(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($mydate.' + '.$daystosum.' days')));
```

- [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will give you a Unix timestamp;
- `date('d-m-Y', $timestamp)` will give you a string like `2022-07-13`;
- Casting that string to an `int` will give you `2022` (and this part is the problem, this makes no sense);
- A timestamp represents "*seconds since Jan 1, 1970*".  2022 seconds after midnight on Jan 1, 1970 is ... Jan 1, 1970, so `date('Y-m-d', $dd);` will give you `1970-01-01`;

Probably the simplest fix is to just change that line to:

```
$dd = strtotime($mydate.' + '.$daystosum.' days');
```

But you are using Laravel, and Laravel comes with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which is extremely useful when working with dates.  Here's a version of your code using Carbon instead:

```
public function orderdatastore(Request $request) {
    $userid = 'GWU458910';
    $orderid = "ORD" . rand(10, 99) . rand(25, 35) . rand(155, 255);
    $pid = $request->product_id;

    // Fetch Product name ny Product id
    $product_data = DB::table('products')->where('product_id', $pid)->first();
    $product_name = $product_data->product_name;
    $selling_price = $product_data->selling_price;

    // Fetch user name by user id
    $customer_data = DB::table('customer_registrations')->where('customer_id', $userid)->first();
    $customer = $product_data->product_name;

    // Use Carbon to parse your input dates
    $fdate = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
    $tdate = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date);

    // Use Carbon to find the difference between start/end dates
    $days = $tdate->diffInDays($fdate);

    // Create a copy of the start date to use for order dates
    $mydate = $fdate->copy();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++) {
        $order = new Orders;
        $order->order_id = $orderid;
        $order->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $order->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $order->user_id = $request->userid;
        $order->user_name = $customer;
        $order->product_name = $product_name;
        $order->product_quantity = $request->quantity;
        $order->order_date = $mydate;

        // Increment order date
        $mydate->addDay();

        $order->product_selling_price = $selling_price;
        // $order->volume = $request->volume;
        $order->order_start_date = $fdate;
        $order->order_end_date = $tdate;
        $order->payment_mode = $request->payment_mode;
        $order->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $order->save();
        echo "All data Saved";
    }
}
```